# Adding previous/next links to a slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

Anyone know how previous/next links could be added to this carousel?

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/uA7NN/

```
    /* home slide show */

var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

slide_len = $(".slideshow_item").size() - 1;

$(".slideshow_item:gt(0)").hide();

slide_int = setInterval(function() {

    slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
    slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

    slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));

    slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
    slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

}, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a quick one:
http://jsfiddle.net/uA7NN/21/

Comment: Just one observation. If you click Next through to the end of the slideshow cycle, you have to wait until it automatically returns to the beginning in order for the Next link to work again. In other words, Next doesn't take it through one cycle of the slideshow to the next.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is pretty simple:

```
/* home slide show */

var $slides = $('.slideshow_item');
var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = $('.slideshow_item').length;

$slides.filter(':gt(0)').hide();

slide_int = setInterval(function() {
    $('#next').click();
}, 2000);

$('#next').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(2000);
    $slides.eq(++slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(2000);

    clearInterval(slide_int);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(2000);
    $slides.eq(--slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(2000);

    clearInterval(slide_int);
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uA7NN/19/**

Comment: It's not working, buttons are working but animation is not continuous.

Comment: True, it's only animating the first two slides and then stops.

Comment: The buttons stop the animation. If you want it to continue, remove the `clearInterval` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the work :)

```
/* home slide show */

var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    slide_len = $(".slideshow_item").size() - 1;

    $(".slideshow_item:gt(0)").hide();

    // Animate function
    function animate(prev) {

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

        if (prev === false) {
            slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));
        } else {
            slide_pos = (slide_pos === 0 ? slide_len : (slide_pos - 1));
        }

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

    }

    // Trigger the animate function
    function init() {
        slide_int = setInterval(function() { animate(false); }, 5000);
    }

    init();

    // Disable animation when slideshow is hovered
    $('#slideshow').hover(
        function() {
            clearInterval(slide_int);
        },
        function() {
            init();
        }
    );

    // Add prev/next actions
    $('.slideshow_prev').click(animate(true));
    $('.slideshow_next').click(animate(false));

});
```